# Adding python script to views.py in django and firing with button click

Tags: python, html, jquery, django, ajax

Total novice here.

Trying to make a web app that generates and displays a random video when a button 
is clicked on a django page.

I have a python script that generates the video.

I have a django project with templates/home.html, views.py, urls.py, and 
my python script videogenfull.py in it. For now it looks like this..

```
views.py: 

from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.shortcuts import render

def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs): 
    print(args, kwargs) 
    print(request.user) 
    return render(request, "home.html", {})
```

```
urls.py: 

from django.contrib import admin 
from django.urls import path

from pages.views import home_view

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('', home_view, name='home'), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls)
]
```

videogenfull.py -  pulls random videos from web, edits them and exports them out as one (very small) video. I have setup a static folder where the generated video will go to and put in some html code in home.html for the video to play.

The html page successfully shows up in my browser - text header and temp video for now.

Next I know that I need to:

- make a html/ajax/jquery button in my html file
- write some code in views.py to get videogenfull.py in there so it fires when the button is clicked

I've been at this last part for a good while and can't figure out how to do it. 
Is this broadly what I need to do?

```
home.html:

<button id="myClickButton" type="button">Click</button>
<div id="myOutput"></div>

$("#myClickButton").click(function() {
    $.get("/output/", function(data) {
        $("#myOutput").html(data);
    }, "html");
});
```

```
views.py:

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'yourapp/index.html')
```

Thanks!

Comment: first write some function in `view.py` which renders at least text `"Hello World"` and assign this function in `path('output/', ...)`. And test if you will see `"Hello World"` when you click button. Later you can do something more useful in this function.

Comment: I can achieve "Hello World" like as I show here but how do I put in views.py and activate on button click?                                            
`def home_view(request,
def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs):
 print(args, kwargs)
 print(request.user)
 return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World</h1>")`

Comment: you have to assign this function to url `urlpatterns = [ path('output/', home_view, name='home'), ...]`  and then button will use it. But it seems you already have other function `home_view` so maybe change its name `def output_view ...` and then `urlpatterns = [ path('output/', output_view, name='output'), ...]`

Comment: I got this error message - still working on it -"Using the URLconf defined in trydjango.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

output/ [name='output']
The empty path didn't match any of these."

Comment: This is how I did the url .... `from pages.views import output_view

urlpatterns = [ 
 path('output/', output_view, name='output'), 

]`

Comment: you have to keep original `path('', home_view, name='home')` in `urlpatterns` to have `home_view` assigned to url `/` (empty path). Without this you get error when you try to open url `/` (empty path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create function in `views.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse 
from django.shortcuts import render

def home_view(request, *args, **kwargs): 
    print(args, kwargs) 
    print(request.user)
    return render(request, "home.html")

def output_view(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
```

Next you have to assign it to url `output/` in urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

from pages.views import home_view, output_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view, name='home'), 
    path('output/', output_view, name='output'), 
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And you have to use `<script>` in `home.html`

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

<button id="myClickButton" type="button">Click</button>

<div id="myOutput"></div>

<script>
  $("#myClickButton").click(function() {
    $.get("/output/", function(data) {
      $("#myOutput").html(data);
    }, "html");
  });
</script>
```

If it works then you can try to use `videogenfull.py` in function `output()`. But it may need more work so I can only show ideas how to use it.

You can run it as subprocess

```
import subprocess

def output_view(requests):
    subprocess.run(["python", "videogenfull.py"])
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hello World</h1>")
```

or you can use it as module - if you have code in function(s) - ie.

```
import videogenfull

def output_view(requests):
    filename = videogenfull.some_function()
    return HttpResponse(f'<h1>Hello World</h1><video src="{filename}"/>')
```

Comment: That works nicely thanks! Now I will look to understand how I should use `videogenfull.py` in function `output()`. I think subprocess is best for me and I tried the above with no luck.

Comment: with subprocess maybe use `["/full/path/to/python", "/full/path/to/videogenfull.py"]` . Both versions run only your script but after that it doesn't know what is full path to downloaded video and what to use in HTML `<video src=.../>` - something like `<video src="/static/video.mp4" />`

Comment: I just tried the first subprocess explanation again and it worked! I should have noticed before 'subprocess' had a typo 'suprocess'. I also needed to install some modules that `videogenfull.py` is using in my django virtual environment. Thanks for all the effort.